# Reducing time complexity for finding all possible triplets in an array?

Tags: algorithms, optimization, arrays

So I have an array sized N. It is sure that array has all distinct elements.

I need to find sum of all possible triplets in that array and for that i need to find all possible triplets.

What i did: looping through array with three nested $for$ loops but that gives O(n^3).

I want to optimise the algorithm as n is very large(upto 10000)

Eg: Array==> {1,2,3,4,5}

Possible triplets: {1,2,3} {1,2,4} {1,2,5} {1,3,4} {1,3,5} {1,4,5} {2,3,4} {2,3,5} {2,4,5} {3,4,5}

Comment: What do you mean by "sum of all possible triplets"? The sum of the elements in each triplet over all triplets?

Comment: @quicksort Yes..

Comment: The beginners mistake: You found an obvious way to get the result, and there is a step in that obvious method taking O (n^3). You try to find a way to do that part faster, instead of stepping back and realising that there is no need actually to solve that problem.

Comment: @gnasher729 Not quite a beginners mistake but a reading mistake , I misread the question quicksort asked above , hence he gave the solution according to it which was pretty obvious..

Comment: Could you clarify what the output is supposed to be? You've commented on an answer that it's not calculating the right thing but the answer looks like a perfectly reasonable interpretation of what you've written.

Comment: The sum of all products of triple elements is an interesting little problem; I guess it's still possible in O (n).

Comment: @gnasher729: Now you made me curious. I'm down to $O(n \log n)$ but, probably due to my ignorance, I don't see the $O(n)$ solution.

Comment: Please edit the question to clarify what you are asking and what you want the output to be.  Your question says you want the sum of all triplets, and your comments says that means " The sum of the elements in each triplet over all triplets?", but a later comment seems to suggest that's not what you want after all.

Answer (score 3):

Finding all the triplets is in fact useless. Let $|A| = n$. Observe that each $a \in A$ appears in exactly $\binom{n-1}{2}$ triplets.

Therefore, the requested sum is just:

$$
\sum_{a \in A} \binom{n-1}{2}a = \binom{n-1}{2} \sum_{a \in A} a
$$

Comment: ... and calculated in O (n).

Comment: Hey, I think i misread you question above , I want the sum of every triplet individually like {1,2,3}=1+2+3=6 {1,2,4}=1+2+4=7

Comment: @AyushGoyal, I'm officially confused. Can you please state your problem formally? What output would you like exactly? If you need even just one symbol per triplet, then you're bound to a solution in $\Omega(n^3)$, as there are $\binom{n}{3} \in \Theta(n^3)$ triplets.

Answer (score 1):

Let n be the length of the array A

```
for (i = 0, i < n - 2, i++)
     for (j = i + 1, j < n - 1, j++)
          for (k = j + 1, k < n - 0, k++) 
               sum += i + j + k
```

You are iterating each result exactly once.  I don't think you are going to do better on the iteration. It is  O($\binom{n}{3}$).  You can get number from [combination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination).

If you look at as every element will appear with every other pair (2) from a set of n-1 then combin(n-1,2) for each element.  Just sum the array and multiply by that number.

$\sum_{a \in A} \binom{n-1}{2}$